# Using sed to change a db script

Tags: sed

I want to move the "ON DELETE CASCADE" from one line to another line, and I want to do it using sed (it's a long story).

I tried the following but I get an error `sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated`s' command`

```
myfunction() {
    sed -i -e 's|
CREATE TABLE IDN_REFERENCE (
  blah
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (CONSUMER_KEY_ID) REFERENCES fff(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ,
  FOREIGN KEY (TOKEN_ID) REFERENCES sss(TOKEN_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (CODE_ID) REFERENCES ppp(CODE_ID)
)|
CREATE TABLE IDN_REFERENCE (
  blah
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (CONSUMER_KEY_ID) REFERENCES fff(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (TOKEN_ID) REFERENCES sss(TOKEN_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ,
  FOREIGN KEY (CODE_ID) REFERENCES ppp(CODE_ID)
)|g' myfile
}
```

Comment: Not clear, please do post sample of input and sample of expected output with code tags i your post and let us know then.

Comment: sed reads one line at a time by default so trying to match the single line currently read against a multi-line string like in your script is not going to work (and even if it could you'd need backslashes at the end of every line). Since you're using GNu sed for `-i` try adding `-z` to read the whole file at one time and puting a backslash at the end of every line in your search and replacement text blocks.